# How to add an alarm function on Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I connected superset to the druid server.

Does superset send alerts when data reaches thresholds?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a practical programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of now Superset is purely a visualization tool, w/o any additional BI functionality.
There was [some talks](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/6615) about this feature in the community, but no implementations so far.

Answer (score -2):

After [release (0.38.0)](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/releases/tag/0.38.0) (published Nov 25th, 2020) it is possible.

Under the menu *Settings* you'll find the *Manage* group and its last item is *Alerts*. Clicking it will allow you to add/setup your alerts.

[image: Superset settings dropdown with an alerts option]